# Angular: Best/recommended way to pass template to child component

Tags: angular, parent-child, ng-template

I was wondering what the best or recommended way is to pass templates to child components. As far as I can see there are basically 3 ways to do this:

## Option 1

**parent.html**

```
<ng-template #mytemplate>
  <!-- some stuff -->
</ng-template>

<child [stuff]="myTemplate"></child>
```

**child.ts**

```
@Input() public stuff: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**child.html**

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="stuff"></ng-container>
```

### Option 2

**parent.html**

```
<child>
  <ng-template #mytemplate>
    <!-- some stuff -->
  </ng-template>
</child>
```

**child.ts**

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) layoutTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**child.html**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="layoutTemplate">
</ng-container>
```

## Option 3

**parent.html**

```
<child>
  <!-- some stuff -> not ng-template around it! -->
</child>
```

**child.ts**

```
// nothing required
```

**child.html**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I was not able to find anything in the docs on what the "standard" way is. 
Is it just taste? Are there benefits for one of them that should make it the default way?

Of course there are always use cases where one or the other is better suited. But I am interested in cases like the example above - where all of them could be used.

Is there already some documentation or recommendation given somewhere? It seems that the examples that you find when searching for "how to pass template to child" are more likely to use Option 2. But why? I would guess this is because they tend to show case examples where the template is not only used to pass it to a child but also in the parent itself as well.

Thanks!

Comment: for me `<ng-content>` rocks

Comment: If the child component needs to have a default template, or repeat the template, or pass it some data, then ng-content is not suitable. In these cases option 2 is what you need. In terms of markup, it's more elegant than Option 1 in general. But option 1 is useful if you want to pass a template to a directive activated by the presence of an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As always, different tools for different things

## Content Projection

Use content projection (**ng-content**) in cases where the html code makes sense to be inline. Consider a custom dropdown in a specific library or some kind of tab solution. It would make the code inelegant and less readable if you had the following:

```
<fantasy-tabs>
   <fantasy-tab [tabContent]="myTemplate">
   <fantasy-tab [tabContent]="myTemplate2">
   <fantasy-tab [tabContent]="myTemplate3">
</fantasy-tabs>
```

Imagine the above, inside a complicated html and the templates declared at the end or at the start of the html.

Content projection is mostly used in libraries for just that reason (it can be used as html as usual), and when the content is not conditional (explanation further down).

For a long time it was also the only option.

## Template outlet

The first and the second solution, are pretty much the same. You are using the `ngTemplateOutlet`. This is pretty much for any other use and it is to be preferred, especially when you have special cases that hide/unhide content.

Thing is that ng-content will always create the child component even if in `ngIf` and destroy it with the parent. So it's better to use `ngTemplateOutlet`

[Check this article here for more information](https://medium.com/@pietmichal/angulars-content-projection-trap-and-why-you-should-consider-using-template-outlet-instead-cc3c4cad87c9)

## Content Child

The `@ContentChild` will query the dom to get the first of a local content, directive etc. It's used to query elements and as such, I expect that it should take a performance hit (but enables you to use when input is just not enough).

Then again, you can't query the dom to get the first element using whatever directive you are searching for.

An example of usage would be if you had a place in your component where you would like to show in a list the highlighted (where highlighted a directive) items of your dom. Then you could use `@ContentChildren` to get them all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed answer! 
Most interesting for me is actually the difference between Opion 1 and Option 2. As I understood, Option 2 is probably more expensive (in terms of performance) than Option 1? Which would mean that Option 1 should be preferrable if there are no other reasons (of which I currently cannot think of - except may be taste and as part of this readability?), would you agree?

Comment: Do you have any references regarding this performance thing? I played around with the first 2 options because I wanted to see how big the performance penalty is (because I personally like Option 2 more tbh). My very stupid example showed almost no difference and if then rather that Option 2 was using less rendering and less scripting time. For the test, I created 1000 components where I passed a template to, either via input or "directly". Because I have the feeling that this kind of testing is rather naive, I wanted to ask if you know other sources/tests which are more reliable? Thanks! :)